# distribute private key with application?

Tags: encryption

I'm building an application and want it to securely transfer data to a server. Thinking to use public/private keys for initial handshake to encrypt a key with which to encrypt subsequent data.

Is it reasonable to have the private key integrated in the executable which will be distributed out in the wild for anyone to reverse-engineer? I also thought of using three-pass protocol, but read about some of its weaknesses and it probably won't work for me

(originally asked in stackoverflow.com, somebody suggested i post it here instead)

Comment: one question: why not the other way around? Have the Public key of the Server to encrypt (like it should be).

Comment: One question: Why reinvent the wheel? What about TLS (likely as HTTPS), possibly with certificate pinning within your application, does not meet your needs?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling the plan is for additional encryption on top of https.

Comment: @Serverfrog client encrypts with server's public key, server response is encrypted with client's public key - isn't that how it works? the question is is it reasonably safe to deploy the client app with the client's private key embedded in the app itself

Comment: why not generate the private key on the device itself instead of shipping it? encrypt this with a password and send the public key from the client to the server in the first communication routins

Comment: @Serverfrog hmm, that's so obvious i'm stunned i missed it. sounds good - thanks!
do i need to encrypt the public key before sending to the server? also - what password, it has to come from somewhere, right?

Comment: @estoy *"the plan is for additional encryption on top of https"* **Why?!** What do you think you can do better than the people designing HTTPS, TLS, and the primitives used therein? What, exactly, about your use case is not met by establishing a TLS-encrypted tunnel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the Answer from Comment Section:

Generate the Private/Public Keypair on the client, encrypt this with a password (maybe choose from the User itself).

The send the Public Key encrypted via Server Public Key to the Server and you have your entire Public/Private Stack.

Comment: You mean reinventing TLS, most likely poorly?

Comment: As he stated for you, he want to use it with TLS. I never mentioned that it was a good way and agree with you but this is the answer for his Question

Comment: indeed, this is the requirement, thanks both for helping out - sounds like a good plan for me